Could not obtain access to "jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe", please start the VM with --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
Using Ecllipse store with micrornaut application facing an issue as Could not obtain access to "jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe", please start the VM with --add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
As per the microstream FAQ - https://docs.microstream.one/manual/storage/faq/java-features.html this is a known issue
Can MicroStream handle Records?
Yes, but due to reflection restrictions of records introduced in Java 15 an export has to be added to the VM parameters:
--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED

This issue is related to the java record, I do have a record in the root as below
public record Country(UUID id,
                      String name,
                      String flagUrl,
                      Optional<Integer> matchPlayed,
                      Optional<Integer> win,
                      Optional<Integer> draw,
                      Optional<Integer> lost,
                      Optional<Integer> points) {
}

I am using the Kotlin version of build.gradle, as per the suggestion I need to add the JVM variable, however I did as below
application {
    mainClass = "fete.bird.EuroApi"
    
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf(
        "--add-exports", "java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED"
    )
}

Still facing the same issue, but during the JUnit test I have set the below argument and everything is working as expected
tasks.test {
    jvmArgs("--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED")
}

Update
Adding this works fine with ./gradlew run
 tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
    jvmArgs("--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED")
}

However not with IntellJ, how to set argument in intellj ?

With Intellj
Add
--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
to the VM option

With Gradle Run
tasks.withType<JavaExec> {
    jvmArgs("--add-exports=java.base/jdk.internal.misc=ALL-UNNAMED")
}


use:
--add-exports java.base/jdk.internal.misc=org.eclipse.serializer.base

instead
